# -finline-functions breaks my code

Tags: c, gcc

I noticed that my code broke at -O3, but not at -O2. I tried applying the flags one by one, and I found that

```
gcc -O1 -finline-functions code.c
```

breaks; and

```
gcc -O1 -fno-inline-functions code.c
```

works.

By "breaks," I mean that it compiles, but it runs incorrectly.

Where should I look for this bug? I can post code, but as it weighs in at 1.5k SLOC, I'd rather not post the whole thing.

Versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxx.xxxx 2.6.18-308.20.1.el5 #1 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
```

Comment: You are using a quite old GCC version, try updating it. This is likely a issue with undefined behavior or some "magic" function like `setjmp`/`longjmp`. Try to find which function causes the problem.

Comment: If you can narrow down the list of functions which might be causing the problem you can then test each one by individually disabling in-lining with the [noinline attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) until you find the actual culprit.

Comment: Go through the process of creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  When it is minimal, if RedHat still supports the compiler you're using, you can try reporting the problem to them.  The GCC team won't be interested in the report against 4.1.x; they've long since given up supporting GCC 4.1.x (according to http://gcc.gnu.org/, 4.7.x is the oldest supported version).  If you can reproduce the problem in 4.7.x or (better) 4.8.x, then you can report it to them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The program works in 4.4.7 with -finline-functions enabled. Odd.

Comment: @sjs Thanks, that let me narrow it down. I figured it out, see answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the bug:

```
int foo() {
  return 5;
}
int bar() {
  foo(); // <-- no return statement!
}
int main() {
  printf("%d", bar());
}
```

See, even though there's no return statement in `bar()`, the value 5 is already in the return value register. `main()` picks up the value in the return register, thinking it's from bar, but really it's from foo. This is undefined behavior, but it only blows up if the compiler tries to inline `bar()`. The solution is to put a return in `bar()`

To gcc's credit, it does warn you if you turn on -Wall

```
code.c:63: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

I found this by manually applying `__attribute__ ((noinline))` (thanks sjs!) to functions until my code worked correctly

Comment: This is not a bug in GCC, this is simply another case of *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Didn't say it was a bug in gcc.

Comment: Wow!  You mean you don't compile with `-Wall -Wextra` all the time?  You can't afford not to use them!